# How to upload entire folder of the directory into Dropbox API ?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

How to upload the entire folder of images (in the particular directory) onto Dropbox using Dropbox API?

In the sample code, it uploads the particular file which is of the same filename, however, I saved the image filenames according to the time at which it is taken and therefore, I was not able to upload any file saved.

I tried to use:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
String imageFileName = "Pictures" + date.toString()+ ".jpg";
File file = new File(path+File.separator, imageFileName);
```

But no file was found when I tried uploading.